# Best practices for button/text arrangement for touchscreen point of sale display GUI

Tags: touch-screen

Would it be ill advised to go ahead with a following button arrangement for a point of sale display touchscreen GUI? It somehow doesn't feel right, I've been toying around with it all morning but can't get an ideal placement for all the buttons.

[image]

- ⌫ - backspace
- deposit - opens up new window (deposit settings - completely
  different option but needs to be updated on the fly in this context)
- ↻ - opens up new window (sets up recurring payment option)
- up/down triangles - allows user to cycle through the textboxes on the right hand side

One of the ideas that has been pestering me is whether I go for a horizontal/vertical arrangement for the **Total Rent**, **Rent Paid** and **Remaining** fields. As this is being built for use in an office used by rather untechnical staff, my concern is that it is clear and easy to pick up from the word go.

Any suggestions for improvement (no matter how radical it seems) would be welcomed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current design there are some possible issues:

- bad visual feedback, as buttons are placed too far from the fields
  [image]
- bad overview, as right-handed user will hide fields with hand while entering
- no feedback of current mode (Total, Paid, Remaining)

.

The possible solution which eliminates the issues is on the image:
[image]

Comment: This is a great answer Alexey, I'm actually speechless. Thank you very much :-)